# How do I move my website logo further up the page

Tags: html, css, markup

I am very new to HTML and CSS and want to move my logo further up the page instead of it being further down towards the centre.

```
   <body>
     <img id="derrick-ogole-logo" src="images/derrick-ogole-logo.png" alt="Derrick Ogole Official Logo">
   </body>
</html>


   #derrick-ogole-logo{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
}
```

How can I move my logo further up so I can add a navigation bar etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is simply using margin-top: and desired percentage. You can use here pixels if you want. You already positioned it vertically by margin-left and right, you can do the same with top and bottom for horizontal position.

I recommend you reading this, everything you need is here, start with basic positioning. [w3schools.com/w3css](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/) Also: [Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_examples.asp) and [How To](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp). I learned a lot there at start.

```css
   #derrick-ogole-logo{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:20%;
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
}
```

```html
   <body>
     <img id="derrick-ogole-logo" src="images/derrick-ogole-logo.png" alt="Derrick Ogole Official Logo">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to put the margin-top at -10% to get it higher up the page because 20% margin-top only takes the logo so far up.

Answer (score 1):

You could also set the `absolute` positions (top/left), then transform based on the image size (kinda based [off of this](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/))

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    #derrick-ogole-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <img id="derrick-ogole-logo" src="https://derrickogole.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-32248_-DERRICK-OGOLE-Logo_-MJ_01.png" alt="Derrick Ogole Official Logo">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, set the top margin to a desired value. To do this you can use the shorthand [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" alt="placeholder">
```

This will set the top and bottom margin, and the side margins will be automatically calculated for you (which will effectively center the image).